Using Regex to parse out style command line parameters starting with - or -- with options
I am trying to parse rsync command line options that start with either a - or --. Some of the -- parameters can also be assigned a value using =. The last two parameters in the example have no option names. They represent the Source and Destination folders.
So here is a literal generic example of the parameters of rsync:
rsync    -av -t --out-format="%M %'10'b %f" --ignore-times   -i --exclude-from = /home/user1/myapppath/exclude.txt   --ignore --link-dest="/home/user1/myback2/abc/2024-09-11T16_55_45" source/abc dest/abc

I found this regex in an old online post (--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>.(?:[^-].+?)?(?:(?=--)|$))?)+? but this does not handle - and also the tail end parameters. I am trying to adapt it. I can handle the last two separately in code if necessary. I am using the PCRE2 implementation. Thanks!
https://regex101.com/r/Gtb1yH/1

Any reason for using a regex here? Most languages have an options parser built into their standard library.

Parsing options is a solved problem. Use existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged. Regexes are not a magic wand to wave at every problem that involves strings. What langauge are you writing in?

Perhaps something like this (?<!\S)--?(?<option>[^\s-][^\s=]*)(?:\s*=\s*(?<value>"[^"]*"|\S+))?|(?<other>\S+) https://regex101.com/r/pSuH9B/1

@Thefourthbird answer above is the accepted answer. It covers all cases including the tail parameters source/destination path. Thanks!

For the example string and the separate parts that you want to match from it, you might use:
(?<!\S)--?(?<option>[^\s-][^\s=]*)(?:\s*=\s*(?<value>"[^"]*"|\S+))?|(?<other>\S+)

The pattern matches:

(?<!\S) Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
--? Match 1 or 2 times -
(?<option> Named group option

[^\s-][^\s=]* Match a single non whitespace char other than - followed by optional non whitespace chars other than =


) Close the group
(?: Non capture group to make the whole part optional

\s*=\s* Match = between optional whitespace chars
(?<value> Named group value with 2 alternatives

"[^"]*"|\S+ Match either "..." or 1+ non whitespace chars


) Close the group


)? Close the group and make it optional
| Or
(?<other>\S+) Named group other matching 1 or more none whitespace chars

See a regex demo.
Note that the last group (?<other>\S+) in this case matches the source and dest part which are at the end of the example string.
But for this part to match, they don't have to be explicitly at the end. This part is an alternative in case the first part of the pattern with option and value do not match. It would also match if source and dest are at the beginning as they are 2 strings that consist of 1 or more non whitespace characters.
So this pattern is a best effort for the given example, which you could extend of course.

This is a great study. Thanks for the breakdown. Accepted answer.

Great explanation, indeed!

Finally! What very nice fresh  colors :)

@bobblebubble Thanks!I wish I could take any credit for it, but it is AI generated. We live in a new era
